# Get data from DB to set as default in dropdown HTML/CSS/MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

Hello guys I want to get data from the DB to set as default/selected in my dropdown.

I have a page named Update Project, in that page I have a dropdown component that is filled by records from my data, however I want to set the selected value from the query result.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 $st_ac = $conn->prepare( "SELECT p.project_code,  m.type
                      FROM tblprojects as p
                      JOIN tblprojectsmaster as m
                      ON p.project_code = m.project_code
                      WHERE p.project_code = :code" );
 $st_ac->execute(array(':code' => $code));

 $result = $st_ac->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $ptype = $result['type']; // the data to be selected in the dropdwon

 <select name="projectType">
                <?php
                for($i=0; $row_pt = $st_pt->fetch(); $i++){
                   $type = $row_pt['type'];
                   $description = $row_pt['description'];

                   echo '<option value"' . $type . '"';
                   if($ptype == $type) 
                      echo 'selected="selected"';
                      echo '>' . $description . '</option>';
                      echo '<br />';

                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $type; ?>"><?php echo $description; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
```

But I can't be able to achieve what I want. Any ideas? Your help will be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<select name="projectType">
                <?php
                for($i=0; $row_pt = $st_pt->fetch(); $i++){
                   $type = $row_pt['type'];
                   $description = $row_pt['description'];
                   echo '<option value="'.$type.'"';
                   if($ptype == $type) 
                   { 
                     echo 'selected="selected"';
                   } 
                  echo '>'.$description.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: ok.. I think you could not store values on $ptype and $type variable. Can you verify that have any values present in $ptype and $type variables

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use like this

```
echo '<option value="' . $type . '"'; if($ptype == $type) { echo 'selected="selected" } >'; echo $description . '</option>'; echo '<br />';
```

Comment: Hey sorry but I'm getting an error :( all other values are not visible